# $\sum_{i\in I} \kappa_i \leq \prod_{i\in I} \lambda_i $ when $\kappa_i < \lambda_i$ for all $i\in I$ and $\kappa_i,\lambda_i$ are cardinals.

Tags: elementary-set-theory, set-theory, cardinals

I am struggling with this exercise, as the title says, I have to prove that $\sum_{i\in I} \kappa_i \leq \prod_{i\in I} \lambda_i $ when $\kappa_i < \lambda_i$ for all $i\in I$ and $\kappa_i,\lambda_i$ are cardinals.

Now, I started from noticing that $\sum_{i\in I} \kappa_i \leq \sum_{i\in I} \lambda_i$ and I tried to work with the definitions.

$\sum_{i\in I}\lambda_i = |\bigcup_{i\in I}(\text{{$i$}}\times\lambda_i)|$

$\prod_{i\in I}\lambda_i = |\{f:I\to\bigcup_{i\in I}\lambda_i : \forall i\in I, f(i)\in\lambda_i\}|$

So I tried to find an injective function between the two sets $\bigcup_{i\in I}(\text{{$i$}}\times\lambda_i)$ and $\{f:I\to\bigcup_{i\in I}\lambda_i : \forall i\in I, f(i)\in\lambda_i\}$ but I have no idea on how to do that. Is that the way to go? If so can you help me with finding such an injective function? Thank you in advance guys :)

Comment: You may need to assume the cardinals are infinite.

Comment: The exercise doesn't state it, but if they were infinite my problem still hold, how do I continue the exercise with this one more hypothesis?

Comment: I was in error. all one needs is that the cardinals all be at least 2. You may find some ideas for your proof in this question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/154653/summation-of-cardinals-is-smaller-than-product-of-cardinals

Comment: @coffeemath I don't think that assumption is needed here. The difference is that in the linked question the cardinals in the sum and product are the same, whereas in this question we have strict inequalities between them.

Comment: On the other hand, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2718261/prove-that-if-1-kappa-i-leq-lambda-i-for-all-i-in-i-then-sum-i-in is *almost* a duplicate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using $\kappa_i < \lambda_i$ we have that $\lambda_i \setminus \kappa_i$ is non-empty for all $i \in I$. Let $f \in \prod_{i \in I} \lambda_i$ be such that $f(i) \in \lambda_i \setminus \kappa_i$ for all $i \in I$. Now for any $(i, \alpha) \in \sum_{i \in I} \kappa_i$ we define
$$
g_{i, \alpha}(j) = \begin{cases}
f(j) & \text{if } j \neq i \\
\alpha & \text{if } j = i
\end{cases}
$$
The assignment $(i, \alpha) \mapsto g_{i,\alpha}$ then is an injection $\sum_{i \in I} \kappa_i \to \prod_{i \in I} \lambda_i$.

Comment: Thank you very much. I thought of another way, since I can find a bijection between the set $\{f:I\to \bigcup_{i\in I} \lambda_i\}$ and the set $\lambda_1\times \dots \times\lambda_n\times\dots$ it suffices to show an injection from $\bigcup_{i\in I}\{i\}\times\kappa_i$ and the above cartesian product. This can be done sending each $(i,\alpha_i)$ to the element $(0,\dots,0,\alpha_i,0,\dots)$ where the  $\alpha_i$ is in the $i$'th entry. This is an injection and so I should have concluded what I was trying to prove. Am I missing something or does this work as well?

Comment: @cento18 It's a similar idea to my answer, but you run into an issue: what happens in the case $\alpha_i = 0$? Essentially my answer avoids this by replacing $0$ for every index by something that is not in $\kappa_i$.